# How to find the speed of SKSpriteNode from 5 frames ago in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

So I have this Swift code using SpriteKit:

```
let ballX = ball.position.x
let ballY = ball.position.y
let ballR = ball.size.width / 2
let sceneW = self.size.width
let sceneH = self.size.height

if ballY >= sceneH - ballR - 3 {
    framesOnTop += 1
} else {
    framesOnTop = 0
}

if framesOnTop > 2 {
    // Some code here
}
```

I have the ball node (SKSpriteNode) that can hit the ceiling and bounce back (scene has no gravity) but sometimes it can hit the ceiling at a very steep angle and get stuck in an infinite loop, left right left right left right. In the if statement that says `framesOnTop > 2` I am successfully detecting when it gets stuck, and I want to make it bounce back down at the right angle with `physicsBody.applyImpulse`. But to do this I need the velocity from before it gets stuck (~5 frames before). Is this possible or is there a better way to fix it?

Comment: It's probably easier to fix your code to not make it stuck then try to store historical velocity values.

Comment: ? It's getting stuck because of a bug, so I'm trying to find a work around.

Comment: Again, it's better in the long run if you solve this issue but to answer your question, you can store your node's CGVector in a NSMutableArray. Every update you add an entry BUT make sure to set a limit on the size of your array. If you don't it will eat up more and more memory.

Comment: You mention physicsBody.applyImpulse.  Typically, you shouldn't need to explicitly handle bounces in a physics simulation like this - it should handle bouncing naturally - which leads me to believe you're not using your physics bodies correctly.  You might be mucking with your physics bodies when you shouldn't be.  Stop doing that, and you will not only fix your problem but vastly simplify your code, too.